# Is there any Google API to check if an input is a city or not?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

Is there any Google API / classes, that can be used to check if a text input is a city or not a city?

I'm developing a real estate iOS app. My app uses GoogleMapSDK for iOS v1.8.1.

Comment: what I've done in my apps is just submit the string the user entered , put Google's autocomplete on there , this is what the user is used to seeing when they actually go to Google Maps and they select a valid address.   If not - send the string to google , then return "Did you mean ... "   and ask them about Google's top 1 or 2 guesses

Comment: Scott Selby: Thanks for your thought. But thats not what I want. I'm looking for an API that return YES if I enter text that is a city name or NO if is not. Do you think Google has it?

Comment: The actual answer is no - does not exist .  You are going to have to get creative if that is exactly what you want and do some comparing with the google response to the user's input

Answer (score 0):

if you are just after US cities , there are many places on the internet that you can get every city and zip code for free - like the US Post Office.  If you can't store all that or don't want to and really want to use Google - then the exact API you are looking for does not exist.   BUT you can actually get the info you want out of the Google API, it will just take some work.  It is easy to send the input to Google Geocoding API, then parse the response and see if the response city matches what the user entered.  I know... this is not ideal, but there are ways to make it look like it's working the way you want from the user's point of view even though the exact API doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `place/autocomplete/json` [API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/autocomplete#place_types):

   - It gives a list of response based on query
   - Simply add "types=(cities)" to your query and Google will return you a list of cities
2. Use `geocode/json` [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

   - Good tool to get GPS location from an address (eg. New York)
   - Simply check the "types" field returned from API, check if it's "locality" or "administrative_area_level_3"

Note: two exceptions are **Hong Kong** and **Macau, MO** both are treated as "country" but they are cities